# Problems with term transformation

Tags: exponential-function

my math book gives the following question: A company sells phones and models the daily sales with the following function: $$f(t) = k*(t-15)*e^{-0,01t}+k*15$$

I have to find the value for t, so that f(t) = 4500 with k = 200

This is where I am stuck:$$200t*e^{-0,01t}-3000e+3000=4500$$

You get this equitation when you set 200 for k. 
I can't figure out how I have to transform the term to get the value of t.

Thanks!

Comment: That should be $200t*e^{-0,01t}-3000e^{\color{red}{-0,01t}}+3000=4500$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A less high-powered approach. I am assuming that since this is a model of daily sales that $t$ is the number of days, and it doesn't make sense to push the value of $t$ any further than the nearest integer. So we just want to find the day that sales pass 4500.

You went a step too far already. you want to put it in this form:
$$200(t -15)e^{-0.01t} + 3000 = 4500$$
Then solve it for the $t$ not in the exponent:
$$200(t -15)e^{-0.01t} = 1500$$
$$(t - 15)e^{-0.01t} = 7.5$$
$$t -15 = 7.5e^{0.01t}$$
$$t = 15 + 7.5e^{t/100}$$
Since $t$ is positive, and is evidently *much* less than $100$, we can expect that $1<e^{t/100}<2$.

Now we go through a process of refining that estimate by use the equation above to produce new limits for $t$. Those new limits provide new limits for $e^{t/100}$, which provides new limits for $t$, etc. We keep this up until the limits on $t$ are within a single day:
$$1<e^{t/100}<2$$
$$22.5 = 15 + 7.5\cdot 1  < t < 15 + 7.5\cdot 2 =30  $$
$$1.25 \approx e^{0.225 }< e^{t/100} < e^{0.3} \approx 1.35$$
$$24.39 < t < 25.124$$
$$1.276 \approx e^{0.2439} < e^{t/100} < e^{0.25124} \approx 1.286$$
$$24.57 < t < 24.64$$

So by the model, sales reach 4500 on day 24.

Answer (score 1):

When you see the variable you are trying to solve for in both the coefficient and exponent, the Lambert W function is always an appropriate path to go.

First, lets isolate the first term.

$200te^{-0.01t}=1500+3000e$

Now transform the first term so that the coefficient is the same as the exponent.

$te^{-0.01t}=7.5+15e$

$-0.01te^{-0.01t}=-0.075-0.15e$

Now take the "$W$" as follows:

$-0.01t=W(-0.075-0.15e)$

$t=-100W(-0.075-0.15e)$

Now, if you want to find the value of that as a decimal, look up "Lamber W calculator".